# Angular5 input fields of array does not show any old value of ngModel when I programmatically push a new value to that array

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular5

My angular5 template looks somewhat like this:

```
<div ngFor="for x of X">

  <input [(ngModel)]="x.name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" maxlength="250" aria-required="true">

  <button (click)="null_append(X)">append</button>
</div>
```

My angular component that is responsible for that template looks somewhat like this:

```
X=[
    {name:null}
  ]
  null_append(o){
    console.log(o);
    var null_found=false;
    for(let c of o){
      console.log(c.name)
      if(c.name==null){

        null_found = true;
      }
    }
    if(!null_found){
      o.push({name: null});
    }
  }
```

The problem that I am facing is that, when a new element is being pushed on that array it stays in the array but the input fields become empty. This is not something I want.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was at the name, I was using the same name in all the input fields. My working version looks like following:

```
<div ngFor="for x of X;let i = index">

  <input [(ngModel)]="x.name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name{{i}}" maxlength="250" aria-required="true">

  <button (click)="null_append(X)">append</button>
</div>
```